# Python searching through columns

Tags: python, loops, csv, datetime

I have a CSV file that I need to loop through in a specific pattern for specific columns and have the output patterns be stored in new files with the same name + "_pattern" + [1,2,3,etc.] + .csv.

This is the search pattern: Loop through column 1 and find the same # and grab them, then loop through column 2 of the grabbed list and then grab all that have the same date in column 2, then go to column 4 and grab all #s that are NOT the same, and then create a file with the pattern from column 1 and 2 and 4 organized by column time.

Example:

```
1       2           time    4
13.45   9/29/2016   6:00    98765
12.56   9/29/2016   6:05    76548
13.45   9/29/2016   6:07    98764
13.45   9/29/2016   6:21    98766
13.45   9/29/2016   6:20    96765
12.56   9/29/2016   6:06    76553
```

[Better view of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqxcG.jpg)

The result would be, file_pattern_1.csv would have:

```
1. 13.45    9/29/2016   6:00    98765
2. 13.45    9/29/2016   6:07    98764
3. 13.45    9/29/2016   6:21    98766
```

But would not include:

```
4. 13.45    9/29/2016   6:20    96765
```

Because column 4 repeats from a previous entry, file_pattern_2.csv would have:

```
1. 12.56    9/29/2016   6:05    76548
2. 12.56    9/29/2016   6:06    76553
```

This is what I have so far but I have become lost on the looping logic:

```
import os

infile = raw_input("Which file are we working with? ")
assert os.path.exists(infile), "Path is incorrect."
os.chdir(infile)

def createFile(csvFile, fileName):
    with open (fileName, 'wb') as ftext:
        ftext.write(csvFile)

def appendFile(csvFile, fileName):
    with open (fileName, 'a') as ftext:
        ftext.write(csvFile)

def setfilename(tread):
    fileName = tread[0:tread.index('.')] + '_patterns' + str(countItem) + '.csv'
    return fileName

for i in pcolumn:
    if pcolumn == pcolumn:
        return pfile
    for x in date:
        if date == date:
            return date
            for a in acolumn:
                if acolumn != acolumn:
                    createFile(fileName)
else:
    print "Finished."
```

Comment: Use the pandas package. `df[['col1','col2','col4']].drop_duplicates()` will help eliminate the duplicates, then iterate over `df.groupby('col1')` to dump out files

Comment: In your example, all of your column 4 entries are unique?

Comment: @MartinEvans That is correct; the column 4 entries are all unquie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you need. It reads a csv file in and generates a matching `datetime` for each of the entries to allow them to be correctly sorted. It creates output csv files based on the pattern number with the entries sorted by date. Column 4 entries already seen are omitted:

```
from itertools import groupby
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import os

filename = 'my_data.csv'
data = []

with open(filename, 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t')
    header = next(csv_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        dt = datetime.strptime('{} {}'.format(row[2], row[1]), '%H:%M %m/%d/%Y')
        data.append([dt] + row)

for index, (k, g) in enumerate(groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[1]), key=lambda x: x[1]), start=1):
    line = 1
    seen = set()

    with open('{}_pattern_{}.csv'.format(os.path.splitext(filename)[0], index), 'wb') as f_output:
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

        for item in sorted(g, key=lambda x: x[0]):
            if item[4] not in seen:
                seen.add(item[4])
                csv_output.writerow([line] + item[1:])
                line += 1
```

Comment: Interesting approach!  Thank you!

Comment: `lambda` is just shorthand for a one line function. It can be replaced with an normal function with a name if needed. So in my case it gets a single argument `x` and returns `x[1]`

Answer (score 1):

As you loop over your files you need to keep a record of which patterns are not eligible for saving. You could use a `set` for this purpose. To group your entries in each file you could use `itertools.groupby`. Using your example:

```python
import itertools

f = [i.split("   ") for i in """1       2           time    4
13.45   9/29/2016   6:00   98765
12.56   9/29/2016   6:05   76548
13.45   9/29/2016   6:07   98764
13.45   9/29/2016   6:21   98766
13.45   9/29/2016   6:20   96765
12.56   9/29/2016   6:06   76553""".split("\n")[1:]]


seen_patterns = set([('9/29/2016', '96765')])   # You need to add entries to this set which you want to exclude

# Sort and group your entries by the first and second columns
col1 = itertools.groupby(sorted(f, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1])), key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
for k, v in col1:
    v = list(v)
    # Filter out patterns which are not allowed
    to_save = [" ".join(i) for i in v if (i[1], i[3]) not in seen_patterns]
    for i in to_save:
        print i  # Save this to an appropriate file
    print

>>>
12.56 9/29/2016 6:05 76548
12.56 9/29/2016 6:06 76553

13.45 9/29/2016 6:00 98765
13.45 9/29/2016 6:07 98764
13.45 9/29/2016 6:21 98766
```

As a further suggestion, have a look at the `glob` module for collecting file paths from directories, it is really useful.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Question: In your code, what exactly does lamba do?  I have seen it and used it before, but never could grasp why lamba worked.

Comment: It can be a bit confusing at first, but lambdas are just syntax for a simple function. I would recommend search for a few examples to help get the idea